# Error: Cannot find module “mongodb” after meteor upgrade to 1.6.1.1

Tags: meteor

edit - There is something strange: mongo appears in both package.json and in .meteor/packages files (should it appear in package.json at all?? it wasn't there before the update) but in different versions. here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "something",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.49",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "google-protobuf": "^3.5.0",
    "grpc": "^1.12.2",
    "grpc-tools": "^1.6.6",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.3.3",
    **"mongodb": "^3.1.0-beta4",**
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "react-progressbar.js": "^0.2.0",
    "react-router": "^3.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

and here is my .meteor/packages:

```
meteor-base@1.3.0             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.5       # Packages for a great mobile UX
**mongo@1.4.2                   # The database Meteor supports right now**
blaze-html-templates@1.0.4 # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
reactive-var@1.0.11            # Reactive variable for tracker
tracker@1.1.3                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifier-css@1.4.0   # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js@2.3.1    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.7.0                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers
ecmascript@0.10.6              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code
shell-server@0.3.1            # Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command

session@1.1.7
tarang:ssl
```

After updating to 1.6.1.1, my app won’t run, crashing with message 'Error: Cannot find module “mongodb” '.

Tried to run meteor npm install, even took away the entire node_modules folder and built it again.

Tried to run meteor npm update.

Tried to run meteor npm install mongodb.

Tried to downgrade back to version 1.6.0.1.

Still can’t find mongodb.

Important - mongodb is there, all collections are there - I can access it through the terminal with "meteor mongo".

Any help?

If it helps - The data in the db can be erased if there is no other way.

(running on ubuntu 16.04)

Thanks

Comment: how did you upgrade to meteor 1.6.1.1?

Comment: Just had exactly the same issue but with a completely new project after adding some packages. I just reproduced the steps with another new project but did not got the error again. Can you post your package.json and the list of your meteor packages? Maybe there is some similarly to be found in the packages.

Comment: @GokhanKaradag, I followed meteor's advise to upgrade to 1.6.1.1 that "has an important patch", and I did it with "meteor update".

Comment: @Jankapunkt, it's strange - mongo appears in both files but in different versions...  I edited the question and added the files. Thanks!

Comment: `meteor reset` erases your `.meteor/local` build folder (including your dev MongoDB data). Many times it solves inconsistent states of a project. You can also manually erase that folder.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the problem was not in the project but in meteor globally, so I uninstalled and re-installed meteor globally, and everything got back to normal…

Thank you all!